# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS when i'm select row in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have problem during selection rows in my table.

When I select any row or try to scroll the table I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

My view is very simple.
After the user press on button, I create table with 10 objects (`Food` class). `Food` is a simple class with id and name. I have an `NSMutableArray` that conatians all the obejcts.

**Thanks for your help!**

The code:

```
@interface SearchFood : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate,   
UITableViewDataSource,    UITableViewDelegate>
{
    UITableView * foodsTable;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *FoodsArray;

-(void)searchButtonClick:(id)sender;

@end


*************************************
import "SearchFood.h"
import "AppDelegate.h"
import "Food.h"

@implementation SearchFood

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Search for food";
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    btnSearch = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [btnSearch setFrame:CGRectMake(220, 10,100, 40)];
    [btnSearch setTitle:@"Serach" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnSearch addTarget:self action:@selector(searchButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self.view addSubview:btnSearch];
    [btnSearch release];

    Food *newfood = [Food new];
    newfood.Food_Name = @"guy";

    self.FoodsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:newfood, nil];
}


-(void)searchButtonClick:(id)sender
{
    foodsTable = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, 320, 460) 
    style:UITableViewStylePlain];


    foodsTable.dataSource = self;
    foodsTable.delegate = self;
    foodsTable.allowsSelection = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:foodsTable];
    [foodsTable release];

}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.FoodsArray count];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Press row");
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"<#MyCell#>";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];

    if (!(indexPath.row >= [self.FoodsArray count]))
    {
        Food * currFood = (Food *)[self.FoodsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = currFood.Food_Name;

        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];
    }

    return cell;
}

*********************
Food class:

@interface Food : NSObject


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* Food_ID;
@property ( nonatomic, retain )    NSString * Food_Name; 

@end

#import "Food.h"

@implementation Food
@synthesize Food_ID;
@synthesize Food_Name;

@end
```

Comment: Your code has a lot of problems! Please read some introduction stuff. For example your naming results in unreadable code. Then you are dequeueing the cell and in the next line you create a new cell. Why? This doesn't make any sense. And this `!(indexPath.row >= [self.FoodsArray count])` is for sure not what you intended to do.

Comment: What do you think `[Food new]` is doing?

Comment: Well, for sure his code has problems. But `!(indexPath.row >= [self.FoodsArray count])` is equivalent to `(indexPath.row < [self.FoodsArray count])` which is absolutly correct, and `[Food new]` is short for `[[Food alloc] init]`

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? When the crash happens, the Console in Xcode should fill with a trace of exactly what went wrong and where. If you could post it, we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If the cell is not initiated a first time, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` returns `nil`. Thus, you can't go ahead with a non-existing cell.

Comment: i'm not sure what u mean. im doing "initWithStyle" to the celll. can u be more spesific please?

Comment: I thought, I saw something different before, did you edit? Now, it seems that you throw away the dequeued cell, but that shouldn't raise your problem. Can you please post the code of the Food class? Maybe also the call trace at the exception would be helpful.

Comment: try UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil){
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
    initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
    reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

Comment: no =\ same error when im select any row. the class is simple . 
2 properties: 
property {nonatomic, retain} NSString *Food_id;
 property {nonatomic, retain} NSString *Food_NAME;

Comment: You talked of 10 objects, in your code is only one. Can there be a problem when you fill your array?

Comment: i dont think so @Matthias...im doing loop
    for (NSDictionary * currNode in allFoods)
    {
        Food *newfood = [Food new];
        newfood.Food_ID =    "somthing..."
        newfood.Food_Name = "something.."
        [self.FoodsArray addObject:newfood];
        [newfood release];
    }
but i cant see any connection to the array..because the exception is when i'm click on cell...and the cell is not object from FoodArray.....

Comment: Well, EXC_BAD_ACCESS means in general that you try to access a released object. Thus, you have a *release* where it does not belong, or a *weak* instead of a *strong* pointer, etc. That's why I ask for the "simple" data structures.

Comment: @Matthias hey, i edit the question and add the code of Food.h and food.m

Comment: New guess: your "something" comes from a dictionary, that will be released. While your Food object is retrained, the string objects are not. Thus, you fill maybe your view with strings that will be released.